# Maven profiles in GWT Super Dev Mode

Tags: eclipse, maven, gwt, web.xml

I have a GWT app which uses Maven for building. I use maven profiles in order to build for different enviroments such as production and test. As an example I have in my web.xml an init-parameter like:

```
<init-param>
        <param-name>USER</param-name>
        <param-value>${USER}</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Then, in my pom.xml I have in my various profiles a property:

```
<USER>"USERNAME-FOR-THIS-PROFILE"</USER>
```

However when I run the app from Eclipse in Super Dev Mode it tries to use ${USER} as a value which obviously does not work very well. Is it possible to make Super Dev Mode use the properties from the appropriate Maven profile?